# Zapier WebHook PHP POST to Webhook

Tags: php, forms, post, zapier

What is your recommended solution for a Zapier Webhook POST Method from a PHP form?

I have made a solution that worked and sent, but for some reason, it is not working.

I have shared code on this post: [Zapier Webhook Issue PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927817/zapier-webhook-issue-php-curl)

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Your Question is based on opinion, which isn't a good fit for Stack overflow, since there is no correct answer.

Comment: I do have another link where I had a solution working, but for some reason Zapier is not getting the actual request body. Im just wondering if this worked for anyone else?